# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source when Adding object to IEnumerable list

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, ienumerable

I am building a simple MVC application to perform CRUD applications. I have two simple model classes.

```
public class MoniModel
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

}

public class MoniGridModel
{
    public IEnumerable<MoniModel> MoniDetails { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller, I am trying to do the following:

```
public ActionResult MoniDetails()
    {
        MoniModel mim = new MoniModel();
        MoniGridModel migm = new MoniGridModel();

        mim.CategoryId = 1;
        mim.CategoryName = "a";
        mim.ProductId = 1;
        mim.ProductName = "b";

        migm.MoniDetails.ToList().Add(mim);

        return View(migm);
    }
```

When migm.MoniDetails.ToList().Add(mim); is executed, it gives the mentioned error. I am not able to figure out why this is happening. I am assigning value to each member of mim object. below is the error detail, not sure if that will help, though.
[image]

Comment: Have you assigned anything to MoniDetails?

Comment: `migm.MoniDetails.ToList().Add(mim);` does absolutely nothing. The list you get from `ToList()` is a new instance, which is immediately thrown away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've never instantiated `MoniDetails` (it's value is `null` when you create the `MoniGridModel`):

```
public ActionResult MoniDetails()
{
    MoniModel mim = new MoniModel();
    MoniGridModel migm = new MoniGridModel();

    mim.CategoryId = 1;
    mim.CategoryName = "a";
    mim.ProductId = 1;
    mim.ProductName = "b";

    var details = new List<MoniModel>();
    details.Add(mim);

    migm.MoniDetails = details;

    return View(migm);
}
```

As @David's answer points out, it's probably best to let the `MoniGridModel` class handle the `IEnumerable<MoniModel>` instead though.

In addition to the options he presents, you could create a private member that backs the `IEnumerable<MoniModel>` and expose it through the getter you currently have:

```
public class MoniGridModel
{
    private List<MoniModel> moniDetails;

    public MoniGridModel()
    {
        this.moniDetails = new List<MoniModel>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<MoniModel> MoniDetails
    {
        get { return this.moniDetails; }
    }

    public void AddDetail(moniDetail detail)
    {
        this.moniDetails.Add(detail);
    }
}
```

And then call `AddDetail` from your controller action:

```
public ActionResult MoniDetails()
{
    MoniModel mim = new MoniModel();
    MoniGridModel migm = new MoniGridModel();

    mim.CategoryId = 1;
    mim.CategoryName = "a";
    mim.ProductId = 1;
    mim.ProductName = "b";

    migm.AddDetail(mim);

    return View(migm);
}
```

Comment: Got it. I should have known this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`MoniDetails` is null because it was never instantiated.  This should generally be done when constructing the object:

```
public class MoniGridModel
{
    public IEnumerable<MoniModel> MoniDetails { get; set; }

    public MoniGridModel()
    {
        MoniDetails = new List<MoniModel>();
    }
}
```

That way consuming code doesn't need to worry about instantiating it.  The responsibility of maintaining the state of the object belongs encapsulated within the object.

Additionally, this doesn't do what you think it does:

```
migm.MoniDetails.ToList().Add(mim);
```

`ToList()` returns an enumerated list of the `IEnumerable<>`.  But you want to add to the enumerable itself.  Given this use, you *probably* want the property to be an `IList<>` in the first place so it can support the `Add()` operation:

```
public class MoniGridModel
{
    public IList<MoniModel> MoniDetails { get; set; }

    public MoniGridModel()
    {
        MoniDetails = new List<MoniModel>();
    }
}
```

Then you can add to it:

```
migm.MoniDetails.Add(mim);
```

Comment: Nicely explained.Thanks.